# Angular interface coming up as undefined

Tags: angular

I have an interface in on of my controls that I instantiate with:

shared:IShared;

Which I import:

import { IShared } from './../../interfaces/i-shared';

And here is my code for the interface:

```
import { IAddress } from './i-address';
import { IEmail } from "./i-email";
import { IPhone } from "./i-phone";
import { IBusiness } from './i-business';

export interface IShared {
        owner_id:string;
        card_color:string;
        card_name:string;
        card_type:string;
        card_subtitle:string;
        company:string;
        title:string;
        linkedin:string;
        linkedin_bus:string;
        facebook:string;
        google:string;
        twitter:string;
        pinterest:string;
        emails: IEmail[];
        phones: IPhone[];
        addresses: IAddress[];
        businesses: IBusiness[];

}
```

But when I try to push something on to 'this.shared.phones' I get the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'phones' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you initialize the phones array before trying to push to it? Maybe, by setting it to an empty array?

Comment: Can you post the logic where you get the error?

Comment: R.Richards: I tried initializing the value for the phones array in the constructor: this.shared.phones = []; But I think it's looking for me to initialize the 'shared' object. When I try to do: this.shared = {}; I get the error: [ts] Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IShared'.

Comment: Ah, figured it out. Needed to initialize: this.shared = <IShared[]>{}; Then initialize this.shared.phones = [];

Comment: @cnak2 you need to initialize `this.shared` to an object that matches your interface. `{}` does not have all of the properties that `IShared` has

Comment: Daniel W Strimpel, this seemed to work:  this.shared = <IShared[]>{};  It that not how I should initialize the shared interface?

Comment: If you want to be able to initialize empty objects for that interface, you'd have to make all the properties optional by following their names with a question mark. The way you have it written, you won't be able to instantiate an object of that type without defining all the properties.

Comment: Thanks, diopside. I completely forgot about that. Thanks!!